# Building in Visual Studio Code with Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'd be absolutely impressed if anyone could help me with this problem which has spiraled out of control.

I just got a computer, so I've been installing all of my software and setting things up. On my old machine, in Visual Studio Code, I had a project that used TypeScript to compile into a single .js file that I could upload to a server (PlayFab specifically). I was able to simply hit Ctrl + Shift + B and the project would build the file (assuming no compile errors, of course).

I don't remember how I had originally installed TypeScript onto that machine, but I'm having a ton of problems on this new one (now Windows 10). I tried installing using `npm install -g typescript` which didn't seem to make any relevant files (specifically the tsc.exe file needed to compile?) and put whatever it did 'install' in AppData. After running that, I tried compiling in VS Code but I got errors about it not knowing what tsc was.

On my old machine, I noticed I had a TypeScript directory under C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript. I went back to the TypeScript site to download an installer, and sure enough I got that directory (in the same place, as well as the matching value in the Path env variable). When I try to compile now, it actually tries opening up the file with another application!? I hastily selected Windows Script Host, and now I just get some random error when it tries opening the file. I went into Default Programs and made it Visual Studio Community, just to see what would happen, and still when I hit Ctrl + Shift + B to compile, it opens up Visual Studio. I have no idea why on Earth using the shortcut to compile (I checked in settings, it is the Ctrl + Shift + B) would attempt to open the file in another application!

So right now my problem is 2-fold. A) Have the Build shortcut attempt to build instead of opening another application, and B) Have the TypeScript successfully instead and transpiled so I can produce my .js file.

I know this was a wordy question, but it's complicated and really causing me a lot of trouble. If anyone can provide any helpful insight, I'm all ears! Please and thank you!

-Matt

Answer (score 0):

There are many extensions related to Typescript in the [Visual Studio Code Market Place.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=typescript&target=VS&category=All%20categories&vsVersion=&sortBy=Relevance)  You should choose the ones you want and load them into VSCode.  I don't know which version of Typescript you want but there is an extension for many versions. The link takes you to the Market Place where I've searched on Typescript.

Comment: Thanks, I may try uninstalling all of my TypeScript installs, as well as VS Code, and moving my project to VS Community 2017. Hopefully I have better luck using one of those extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the problems above, but I did manage to get around it. As mentioned in my comment, I simply got rid of VS Code (which is a shame because I did like its simplicity) and instead, I'm using VS Community 2017.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems using typescript in VS Code when I had Visual Studio community installed with the typescript SDK.

When i tried running TSC (typesciprt compiler) from vscode's terminal, I kept getting a window host error. As it is seeing tsc.js in the program files\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript directory before it gets to typscript complier.

So from the vscode terminal install the typescript compiler locally to the project:

```
npm install typescript --save-dev
```

We can then use the typescript compiler by using referencing the project install e.g. to build Main.ts file I can use in vscode terminal:

```
.\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd .\src\Main.ts
```

Assuming you are in the root folder for your project